# Symfony 2 - generate select list with same values

Tags: forms, symfony, select

Is it possible to generate a Custom Select Type with same values, like this :

```
How many cigarettes do you smoke a day ?
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="">Choose option</option>
    <option value="0">0 cigarettes</option>
    <option value="0">1 cigarettes</option>
    <option value="0">2 cigarettes</option>
    <option value="5">5 cigarettes</option>
    <option value="10">More than 5 cigarettes</option>
</select>
```

My issue is that all 0 values are overriden at the creation of choice array.

```
array(
    "0" => "2 cigarettes"
    "5" => "5 cigarettes"
    "10" =>" More than 5 cigarettes"
)
```

Any idea to change the structure of choice array giving as Default Option in my Select Custom Type ?

Thanks.

Comment: really hard to understand what you want to achieve. If you do not want the value 0 to be overwritten you could probably just use a multidimensional array?

Comment: Yes but Symfony can interpret a multidimensional array as choices ?

Comment: You can't really do this as this would create ambiguity on submission of the form. If the value is 0 which of the options would be selected (0, 1 or 2)?

Comment: The aim is that 0 1 or 2 have the same "weight", which might be "0".

Comment: Maybe you could give values such as 0_0, 0_1, 0_2? then use explode() function or something to analyse data afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `choice_list` option instead of `choices`. It must be an instance of **ChoiceListInterface** like the **ChoiceList** class, where the choices and the labels are passed in two array in the constructor.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-list.